# LoginView control analogue in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rendering, conditional-statements

How do you do conditional content rendering in ASP.NET MVC depending on `User.IsInRole()`? Tried all matches i could find here, at SO but still not satisfied. I need to hide action links depending on user roles so first i thought of a helper like

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string linkUrl, string linkText, object htmlAttributes, bool alwaysVisible, params string[] roles)
```

but then I realized that I often needed to hide the outer content too (for example, `<li></li>` in the menu where my links were placed into). I follow the recommendation from [best practices](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx) and have `UrlHelperExtension` so my typical links look like:

```
<a href="@Url.SomeStuff()">some stuff</a>
```

and I can't try the idea to implement the helper over `RouteLink()` that will grab `AuthorizeAttribute` from appropriate controller methods can I?. What's your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to use something along the lines of:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Role")) {
<li>
  <a href="@Url.SomeStuff()">Some stuff</a>
<li>
}
```

This way I can have multiple links per role if needed.

Comment: Yeah, looks simple at first glance but in large application this will lead to tag soup. And we know advise from Rob Conery - "If there's an IF, make a Helper".

Comment: An alternative could be to create another helper something like ListItemActionLink that calls your custom ActionLink helper but just puts the resulting string in an li tag (it the string is empty just return a string). A more generic approach would be to create a TagActionLink where you can pass the tag in (and html attributes if you want). This would give a cleaner layout.

Answer (score -3):

Another way you could possibly approach this is by using either CSS to hide the elements you want hidden based on roles e.g.

```
<li class=@(User.IsInRole('role')?"showClass":"hideClass")>
  <a href="@Url.SomeStuff()">Some stuff</a>
<li>
```

or perhaps something with Jquery, such as:

```
    <li class="@User.Role")>
      <a href="@Url.SomeStuff()">Some stuff</a>
    <li>

    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".SomeRole").hide()
    }
```

Comment: Yuck, javascript based security, easily bypassed by anyone who can press F12 or disable javascript.